# Inserting CCParticleSystemQuad between sprites in different CCSpriteBatchNode's

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, kobold2d

I currently have a few layers in a Cocos2d scene (running in Kobold2d). Each layer has a sprite batch node attached to it. I need to use batch nodes given the ridiculous number of sprites I have on screen at once. Everything is working fine, and I've set up a little particle system. Problem I'm running into is CCParticleBatchNode particle emmiters are always on top of everything (as it is the highest zOrder's layer) - but this is an isometric game and obviously doesn't work.

Is there a way that I could sneak the emmiters between the sprites on any of my layers containing CCSpriteBatchNode's? I've tried messing around with vertexZ (I'm on the newest version of cocos2d 2.+) but it doesn't matter what I do, it doesn't seem to change anything, even though the LUA file for Kobold2d that would enable this is set properly and the shader for programForKey:kCCShader_PositionTextureColorAlphaTest on my batch nodes is enabled - but maybe this isn't even the best solution?

Has anyone run into anything like this or suggest any sacrifices I could make or tricks I could do that I'm not thinking of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use vertexZ you need to enable depth buffering (see config.lua). Vertexz is the only way to change draw order between spritebatches and other nodes.

Comment: `
  DefaultTexturePixelFormat = TexturePixelFormat.RGBA8888,
  GLViewColorFormat = GLViewColorFormat.RGB565,
  GLViewDepthFormat = GLViewDepthFormat.Depth24Bit, -- Depth buffer required for correct Z ordering of Iso tiles
  GLViewMultiSampling = NO,
  GLViewNumberOfSamples = 0,

  Enable2DProjection = YES,       
  EnableRetinaDisplaySupport = NO,
  EnableGLViewNodeHitTesting = NO,
  EnableStatusBar = NO,`

It's possible I don't have it set properly, is this correct?

Comment: Regardless, considered answered since you're pretty much the source on all things such. Thanks for narrowing my focus.

Comment: Depth16Bit should be enough. Besides I think either 16 or 24 bit depth buffer option no longer exist, can't remember which one though.